# How to put a \dot accent above a \hat accent in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents

I use `${\dot \hat E}$` to put a hat and dot on top of an E simultaneously. However, an error occurs.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: `$\dot{\hat{E}}$` should help ...

Answer (score 11):

First, be sure to load the `amsmath` package, as it provides for better positioning of stacked math accents. Second, write

```
$\dot{\hat{E}}$
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\dot{\hat{E}}$ 
\end{document}
```

Just for comparison, here's the output of `\dot{\hat{E}}` if the `amsmath` package is *not* loaded:

[image]

Comment: This shows why it's preferable to always teach the “braced  syntax"

Comment: Question of taste for you @Mico:  if dot denotes time derivative and hat denotes preferred reference frame, would it make more sense to `\hat{\dot\omega}` or `\dot{\hat\omega}`?

Comment: Perhaps `\frac{d\hat\omega_k}{dt}` makes the moist sense.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Thanks for these comments. I will readily concede that your understanding of what the dot and hat accents may mean is probably (almost surely, actually! -- I'm an economist; dot-accents tend to be used but rarely in mathematical economics and econometrics) a lot better than mine. I especially like the suggestion of not using both accents in combination and to "differential fraction" notation instead. Readers will quite likely agree.